# python | fastest float key dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make a dictionary with all float keys in it and I was wondering what would be the best or more importantly fastest way of implementing it.

Specification:

1. this is a dictionary where all keys in dict[keys] are float
2. at any key k I need to be able to jump to key x where x is the closest key, where x > k and also I need to be able to go to the closest key where x < k
3. I need to be able to specify a range, for example (3, 9) and it will give me all the keys within that range
4. I also need to be able to add any key into the dict so that specification 1, 2 and 3 applies to it

At first I was thinking of using OrderedDict to do this but it does not have any insert functions and any insert functions I found are slow. So my question is, what would be the fastest way of implementing this dictionary?

Comment: Any binary search tree seems like it should work for that. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bintrees?

Comment: Interesting problem, but I think the mention of dictionaries is confusing here. My first thought was: using floats as keys is a bad idea. You are rather looking for a different data structure like a tree or linked list.

Comment: Well linked lists don't really fit because my data is so big. The reason why I need float is because at any point in time I need to be able to add another key between x and k. Don't binary trees have to have a set length n=5 (01101)

Comment: @JökullSnærGylfason: No. What? The whole point of a “self-balancing binary tree” is to allow for efficient access after insertions or deletions. `std::map` in C++ is commonly implemented with a red-black tree.

Comment: Okey I'll try to implement a binary tree for this problem

Comment: Are the contents also floating point numbers? If so you should look at using `numpy`.

Comment: Nope they are objects @rolandsmith and I dont see how numpy could saticfy the specifications I need